# Creating a generator expression from a list in python

Tags: python, list, generator, functional-programming

What is the best way to do the following in Python:

```
for item in [ x.attr for x in some_list ]:
    do_something_with(item)
```

This may be a nub question, but isn't the list comprehension generating a new list that we don't need and just taking up memory? Wouldn't it be better if we could make an iterator-like list comprehension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes (to both of your questions).

By using parentheses instead of brackets you can make what's called a "generator expression" for that sequence, which does exactly what you've proposed. It lets you iterate over the sequence without allocating a list to hold all the elements simultaneously.

```
for item in (x.attr for x in some_list):
    do_something_with(item)
```

The details of generator expressions are documented in [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could use parenthesis like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
for x in some_list:
    do_something_with(x.attr)
```

Comment: Well it's a bit more complicated than that in my case :) This was a simple example I gave to illustrate the point. I had to use reduce(), but now I can just do with any() and all() :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged `functional-programming` without an appropriate answer, so here's a functional solution:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

map(do_something_with, map(itemgetter('attr'), some_list))
```

Python 3's `map()` uses an iterator, but Python 2 creates a list. For Python 2 use `itertools.imap()` instead.

If you're returning `some_list`, you can simplify it further using a generator expression and lazy evaluation :

```py
def foo(some_list):
    return (do_something_with(item.attr) for item in some_list)
```